# Postgis extension doesn't seem to be taken into account when restoring a PostGIS database: ERROR: type "public.geometry" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am struggling trying to restore a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) dump that has been made using `pg_dump` (v. 12+) out of a production database having [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) installed, the very first issue is this one when restoring the dump:

```
db_1   | pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.global_position"
db_1   | [189] ERROR:  type "public.geometry" does not exist at character 94
```

to me, this roughly means that the postgis extension was not successfully restored.

But when I log on the original database in order to list the installed extensions, here's what I can read:

```
You are connected to database "productiondb" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" (address "127.0.0.1") at port "5432".
productiondb=# \dx
                                         List of installed extensions
       Name       | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 fuzzystrmatch    | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
 plpgsql          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis          | 2.5.2   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology | 2.5.2   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(4 rows)
```

so postgis is actually there, inside the public schema.

Therefore, why is the postgis extension not restored properly? Is there something special about it?

Here are some more details:

```
productiondb=# select version();
                                        version                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 8.2.0) 8.2.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

productiondb=# select postgis_version();
            postgis_version            
---------------------------------------
 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
```

And the dump was made using:

```
pg_dump -Fc -d "postgresql://postgres:****@localhost:5432/productiondb" \
  --disable-triggers \
  --role=postgres \
  --no-owner \
  --no-acl \
  --verbose \
  -n "public" \
  -f "file.dump"
```

And restored as follows (inside a local docker container):

```
pg_restore --format=c \
  -U postgres \
  -d postgres
  --verbose \
  --clean \
  --create \
  --no-privileges \
  --no-owner \
  file.dump;
```

Comment: What does v. 12+ mean?  What specific version did you try, and how did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

While extensions can be associated with a schema, they are not actually *in* the schema.  For example, you can't create the same extension associated with different schemas in the same database at the same time; which you could if they were actually in a schema.

So specifying `-n` with pg_dump means the extension create statements do not get dumped, so pg_restore doesn't replay the extension creation.

You could create the extension manually.

Comment: Thank you, I begin to understand the underlying behavior, but now that I manually created the `postgis` extension, I'm facing another [issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295257/restoring-a-dump-of-a-schema-made-with-the-n-option-of-pg-dump-of-a-postgis-d) when restoring a dump file that has been done on the public schema only.